# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch') on guild.members.fetch()

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am working on setting a script that will cycle thorough all the members in a guild without using the cache system. I am getting an issue where when I use guild.members.fetch() it treats guild.members as undefined. I know it isn't because I am currently logging guild.members and it is giving me a GuildMemberManager object. I don't understand when once I use fetch() on it, it is suddenly being viewed as undefined.
[Here is a screenshot of the entire error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDdrG.png)

```
function addMissingJsons(message, bot) {
    bot.guilds.fetch("id").then(guild => {
        console.log(guild.members);
        guild.memebers.fetch().then(members => {
            console.log(members);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It should be `guild.members` not `guild.memebers`.

Comment: Do you mean guild.members. instead of guild.memebers. ?

Comment: Yes. @jeremy-denis

Comment: @mswgen @ jeremy-denis Oh my god! I don't know how I didn't catch that! Thank you guys for point out my error!

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the best answer to close the thread? @saxon564

Comment: @K.KDesgins Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@mswgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13065777/mswgen) said, you have a typo. It should be `guild.members` not `guild.memebers`. Your code should look like this:

```js
function addMissingJsons(message, bot) {
    bot.guilds.fetch("id").then(guild => {
        console.log(guild.members);
        guild.members.fetch().then(members => {
            console.log(members);
        });
    });
}
```

*Since the comment worked, this is just a response for you to mark as the best answer to close the thread.*